# gppg/gplex equivalent in D?

Tags: parsing, d, abstract-syntax-tree, lexical-analysis, gppg

When I was working in C#, I found the [gppg](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gppg/) and [gplex](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gplex/) parser/lexer generators to be perfect for my needs. I'm wondering if there's something similar for the D programming language (i.e. a utility that, given a grammar in BNF or EBNF, outputs D code that lexes/parses that language into a abstract syntax tree).

The closest I've found is [Goldie](http://www.semitwist.com/goldie/), but I'm having so much trouble understanding it that I'm not able to get anything up and running.

Comment: I'm not sure you really want it to output *code*. That was for the C era, when metaprogramming wasn't possible. I think a better choice might be to have it be a template instead, to be instantiated by the user code.

Comment: This sounds intriguing, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found Goldie pretty awesome for context-insensitive grammars, are you sure about it? Also, http://www.wikiservice.at/d/wiki.cgi?GrammarParsers lists some, no idea which are still developed. If ANTLR-D still works, it is probably on of the best choices.

Comment: FWIW, the template-based parser listed is mine and it worked under D1 for many cases last time I checked, but that was over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Goldie is probably your best bet, but there's also ragel which can emit D. It's not exactly what you asked for (composable state machines) though it might suffice for many cases and it's really nice.

Trunk version can compile to D2 code with the undocumented -E switch, I'm not sure yet how mature that is.

http://www.complang.org/ragel/